# Error "Unknown Unicode character" using unicode math symbols

Tags: pdftex, input-encodings

When I use pdflatex to convert a file having unicode math symbols, it complains about that it is not found.  How should I handle that?  It seems to offer me a way to insert the character to a system file... and I'm unsure if that's the right thing to do.

```
! Package ucs Error: Unknown Unicode character 8289 = U+2061,
(ucs)                possibly declared in uni-32.def.

l.1802 \[(,)=\exp⁡
                                (−(,)(−))=\frac{...
```

Comment: please always post a small complete document that reproduces the problem, that is not the message from the standard latex unicode support so (for some reason?) you have loaded a variant from ucs package, but either way the standard `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2061}{}` will define the character to do nothing, which is what you need here (it is invisible function application marker)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle as the OP is presumably using `utf8x`, the correct syntax is `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{"2061}{}` or `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{8289}{}` using the decimal code point which is given in the ucs error message.

Comment: This post might help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/464393/why-am-i-getting-unidcode-error-for-some-equations-when-microsoft-got-upgraded-f?noredirect=1#comment1168553_464393

Answer (score 2):

You are using `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}`, in all probability, and following the error message you can fix that this way:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{"2061}{}% use TeX input syntax for numbers, here hexadecimal (works only with utf8x)
\begin{document}
\[(,)=\exp⁡(−(,)(−))=\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

As per `uni-32.def` it is found in TeXLive 2018 at `/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ucs/data/uni-32.def` it is a support file for `ucs` package. When using `utf8x` option to `inputenc` you trigger `ucs` (partial) usage. But it contains no definition for Unicode code point U+2061.