# Undefined reference for labelled equation

Tags: cross-referencing, labels, undefined

I have the following weird (to me) problem with Texmaker: I have some labeled equations lines in a `A.tex` file within master file `M.tex`. There are three specific equation lines among them which I just can't reference: whenever I type \ref{Name of equation} and compile, I get "(??)" for those three equations (no matter how many times I compile). All the other surrounding equations compile.

I am 100% certain there is  no typo when passing from `\label` to `\ref`.

Stranger: when I cut the paragraph containing the equations and the references to them and paste it a few paragraphs above in the same `A.tex` file or even in another `B.tex` file (different section of the same document) in the same master file `M.tex`, everything works fine.

Stranger still: when I cut the whole content of file `A.tex` and paste it in a new file `C.tex` and then replace `A.tex` by `C.tex` in `M.tex`, same problem pops up.

I guess this is a bit vague; but just in case someone has encountered a similar problem. I have had this issue for months (it is in a math paper I am writing): 3 weeks ago, I don't know why, it worked for a few days, then the issue came back. If it helps, I use BibTeX. However this is not a problem about bibliography.

Here is one of the equations. Sorry for the format (first time asking a question here)

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper, leqno]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\label{Variation 5}
\Psi^j(a_f^{\alpha}(t)\lvert H)=a_f^{\alpha}(t)\lvert H \quad {\rm and} \quad \Psi^j ({\rm sw}_f^{\beta} (t)\lvert H)={\rm sw}_f^{\beta} (t)\lvert H.
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Do you have empty lines in your equation environment? If  so, you should get errors, and cannot expect consistent results.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat No, no empty lines. The equation seems fine: it compiles and appears in the pdf output. But, when I reference it a few lines below, I get a warning 'Undefined defined reference in line ...' and (??) in the pdf file.

Comment: In the code you show there are empty lines. Anyway, try `\label{Variation_5}` instead of `\label{Variation 5}`, i.e. replace the space by an underscore. (BTW, in order to mark code as code, put it in the cursor and press the `{}` button. I did that now in your code, of course after double checking that there are no empty lines.)

Comment: Apart from the lack of `\usepackage{amsmath}`, this example compiles and the refernce is shown as expected. So it's impossible to debug your problem. As an aside, the command `\rm` has been obsolete and deprecated for more than 25 years. And `\lvert` is not the right command for those cases, `\vert` is right.

Comment: @egreg I indeed use \usepackage{amsmath}. The problem is not the compilation but the referencing. What is the replacement for the command \rm ?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I just tried that, to no avail. In fact, I have tried changing the name many times.

Comment: Thanks anyway. Hopefully, I will solve this by the time I finish writing the paper.

Comment: You should use `\text{and}` for textual insertions; for the operator `sw`, you should add `\DeclareMathOperator{\sw}{sw}` to your document preamble and use `\sw` in the body.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for the tips !

Comment: @A.B. I have no clue what could cause your problem, but if placing the problematic code further up in your file makes it work, I'd guess it has something to do with what's in between. Otherwise, maybe deleting your `.aux` & co. files and recompiling from scratch could help?

Comment: @steve To all: Thanks. Problem solved. It turn out there is some explanation by latex below the mention 'Reference on page ... undefined (I usually reads only error compilation messages in red). Copying the message on google search led to the answer here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/464238/error-unknown-unicode-character-using-unicode-math-symbols. The code given there solved the issue (though I still don't get what it was). Thanks